# find members of groups excluding disabled users

Tags: powershell

I have 10 security groups all that are called " 'companyname' RDS Users"

I am trying to create a script that does the following: List all the groups and then list all of the members excluding the disabled members, then have it email a csv. I have done the following but cant get the disabled user excluded.

The Script belows shows how far i got but the disabled users show in there which basically means the script is pointless.

```
$mailServer = ""
$mailFrom = ""   
$mailTo = ""    
$mailSubject = ""    
$file = "somepath\RDSUsers.csv"      

Import-Module ActiveDirectory   

$US = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property Enabled |where {$_.Enabled -eq "True"}| FT Name, Enabled -Autosize

$Groups = (Get-AdGroup -filter * | Where {$_.name -like "*RDS Users" -and $_.name -ne "RDS Users"}| select name -expandproperty name)

$Table = @()

$Record = [ordered]@{
    "Group Name" = ""
    "Name" = ""
    "Username" = ""
} 

Foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{
    $Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $Group |select name,samaccountname
    foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers)
    {
        $Record."Group Name" = $Group
        $Record."Name" = $Member.name
        $Record."UserName" = $Member.samaccountname
        $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record
        $Table += $objrecord 
    }
}

if ($Table -eq "RDS Users") {}
$Table
```

there is usualy a line here that sends the email with excel attachment

Comment: you used `FT Name, Enabled -Autosize` - the `Format-*` cmdlets are NOT supposed to be used for anything other than FINAL output  to the screen or a plain text file. it _butchers_ your objects, wraps them in formatting code, and then spits them out. use `Select-Object` instead since that is what it is _designed for. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should produce the output you want in the `$Table` variable. You can then pipe `$Table` to one of the `format-*` commands.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$US = Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq '$true'" -Property Enabled
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like '*RDS Users' -and Name -ne 'RDS Users'" |
             Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$Table = Foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{
    try
    {
        $Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName
        $compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $US -DifferenceObject $Arrayofmembers -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual -PassThru -Property SamAccountName -ErrorAction Stop |
        Select-Object Name, SamAccountName
        $compare | ForEach-Object {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                "Group Name" = $Group
                "Name"       = $_.Name
                "UserName"   = $_.SamAccountName
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            "Group Name" = $Group
            "Name" = $null
            "UserName" = $null
        }
        Continue
    }
}
$Table
```

**Explanation:**

The `Get-ADGroupMember` command will not provide the `Enabled` property of its returned objects. You will need to feed its output into another command like `Get-ADUser` for that data. Since you already stored all of the enabled users in `$US`, we can simply compare `$US` collection to the results of each `Get-ADGroupMember` output.

I removed most of the `Where-Object` commands in favor of using the `-Filter` parameter on the AD commands. Almost always, the `-Filter` parameter will be faster especially when you are comparing AD indexed attributes like `Name` and `Enabled`.

You do not need to store each output object in a variable unless you are going to further manipulate it. This is why `$Record` was removed. Instead, all returned objects are stored in the array `$Table`. I removed the `+=` operator mainly because of its inefficiency when repeatedly building arrays. Also, you can simply set a variable to the output of a `foreach` loop, which will result in the array you require. Since we created a custom object on each loop iteration and provided the properties at the time of declaration, `[ordered]` is not required. However, if you create the hash table first and then create a corresponding object, you will potentially need to use `[ordered]`. As an aside when you are creating custom objects that are involved in a loop, it is usually best practice to create a new object each time. Otherwise, you could unintentionally update values on the wrong objects. Just because you add an object to an array, you can still update its properties after the fact.

The `Compare-Object` command ties everything together. The `-ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual` parameter combination will only output objects with matching property values. Since we are comparing `$Arrayofmembers` and `$US`, that is ideal. The `-PassThru` switch allows the objects to be returned with all of the properties that were passed into the command. Then you can use the `Select-Object` command to pick which properties matter to you.

Comment: This is great, thank you so much i really appreciate the effort....Unfortunately it does not work :-( I get..Compare-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'DifferenceObject' because it is null. My hopeful output was a list of the RDS User Groups and there members, excluding the disabled users. Sorry not great at powershell this is more advanced than i usually would write, thats how we get better though !

Comment: is the `$groups` output `$null`?

Comment: This is my exact error..........Compare-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'DifferenceObject' because it is null.
At C:RDS_Users.ps1:16 char:70
+ ... Object -ReferenceObject $US -DifferenceObject $Arrayofmembers -Exclud ...
+                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Compare-Object], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CompareObjectCommand

Comment: Does the script stop at an error or does it just output errors to the console and continues to process?

Comment: That means your `$ErrorActionPreference` is not continue. So we will need to add that into the commands.

Comment: I've updated the code to do error handling. You should give it a go again.

Comment: it goes through but with no output.

Comment: The output is stored in `$Table`. You need to type `$Table` at the console or put it on a line at the end of the script if it is a script file.

Comment: Ok Brill that worked ! just does not display all the users its displays like 3 in {user user1 user2} and thats it. again thanks so much for your help

Comment: @user9581555 How do you want those users to be displayed?

Comment: the group then the name of the person in that group.

Comment: So if there are three users in one group, you want that group listed three times with one user per line?

Comment: yes or top row with the group name and then under than the users